# PWA Vue JS App doesn't displayed on devices

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I tried to run my PWA App on devices but I have some problem.

On an Android Smartphone (Honor) : Works with google chrome, and after add app to home screen.

On an Android tablet (Samsung) : Works with google Chrome but white screen after add app to home screen.

On IOS Smartphone : White screen on safari.

On IOS Ipad : White screen on safari. With this error : "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name."

There is my my manifest.json :

```
{
  "name": "ox-mobile",
  "short_name": "ox-mobile",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#4DBA87",
}
```

And my router.ts :

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      alias: '/',
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'auth',
      component: Auth,
      alias: '/',
    },
    {
      path: '/logout',
      name: 'logout',
      component: Logout,
      alias: '/',
    },
  ],
```

Someone had same issue ?

Comment: `Unexpected token '...'` generally means you are using a JavaScript feature that the browser doesn't support. You probably need to use babel or similar tool to transpile some features.

Answer (score 0):

Abraham is correct, the error with ... is almost certainly a browser not supporting ES6.

It depends how you build your app, as to how you fix the problem.

If you are using Vue CLI, then [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58887172/209288) to a similar question.

e.g.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 "transpileDependencies": [
   "yourES6package"
 ],}
```

For webpack directly use something like:

```
build: {
    transpile: ['yourES6package']
}
```

There may be other solutions, e.g. using an earlier version of the npm package in ES5.